How to generate a Java model for an OpenAPI enum whose name starts with a digit?
I have been provided with an OpenAPI YAML spec by the vendor to implement the REST calls, the spec has one enum element 3RIIndicator. I'm using openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate the Java model classes on my side, but in the generated class it gives compilation error for this enum because it starts with digit '3' and Java doesn't allow enum to start with digit. Is there any way to get around this, any option in the Maven plugin that can be used?
3RIIndicator:
    type: string
    description: 'xxx'
    enum:
      - Recurringtransaction
      - Installmenttransaction
      - AddCard

I tried using openapi and swagger maven plugin to generate the model classes, but the generated classes have enum name as 3RIIndicator which Java still complains.

Here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md search for: reservedWordsMappings

Always read the documentation of the tools you are using.
